# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression error in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a problem here in React js and it says

Error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Error is in this function and here is it:

```
const generateKey = (dataKey) => {
  let output = [];
  let withKeys;

  for (let i = 0; i < dataKey.length; i++){
    withKeys = {
      ...dataKey[i],
      key: i,
    },

    output.push(withKeys);
  }

  return output;
}
```

I don't know whats the problem in here. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Paste the full component code.

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. I removed references to React since the code you shared doesn't look related to React, but if you feel it's relevant (and you're adding an example that uses React), please add the tag back but still avoid listing tech in the title.

Comment: Line 6, from 

withKeys={
...dataKey[i],
key: i,
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inside the `for` loop. There should be a semicolon instead of comma. Fix it like below:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < dataKey.length; i++){
    withKeys = {
    ...dataKey[i],
    key: i,
    };
    output.push(withKeys);
  }
```

Comment: It worked, I see that the problem is the comma after the closing bracket, it should be semicolon instead of comma. Thank you